# Validating Mobile number using React - validator library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation

I'm looking to validate the mobile number using 'validator' package in react.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator

---

The problem i am currently facing is the function is accepting 11 digit mobile number. How can I solve this

Actual Behaviour:

```
isValidNumber('+91998877665511') :- false (12 digits)
isValidNumber('+9199887766551') :- true (11 digits)
```

Expected Behaviour:

```
isValidNumber('+919988776655') :- true (10 digits)
isValidNumber('+91998877665511') :- false  (12 digits)
isValidNumber('+9199887766551') :- false (11 digits)
```

*Note:* this count of digits is with country code excluded

Comment: Use two validators - isValidNumber() and isLength() like `isValidNumber('1234567890') && isLength('1234567890', {min: 10, max: 10})`

Comment: Do not validate the mobile number (based on length or format etc). The best to validate a mobile number is by sending a code (OTP) to the mobile and asking the user to enter it. Only this will make sure that the number is valid and active.

Answer (score 0):

Use two validators - isValidNumber() and isLength() like

```
isValidNumber('1234567890') && isLength('1234567890', {min: 10, max: 10})
```

Comment: what if the number has +91 for india or any other code 354 for iceland ?

Comment: Interesting. So ideally, you should have two input boxes, one for the country code and another for the contact number. Try this library of Google - https://github.com/google/libphonenumber

Comment: but what validator package does is it checks the code also, but there is a bug in the package which is accepting number with 11 digits also (excluding the code)